# Green's function. Basic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Can anyone give some advice about books where I could find introductory information about Green's function. What are the methods of constructing Green's function. 
Actually, Green's function for 3D diffusion equation in unbounded domain is of interest. 
I am novice in this topic (Green's function for ODE and PDE) and any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think that "Boundary Value Problems and Green's Functions" by Stakgold and Holst is a good text.

Comment: By the way, for the classical linear pde's Evans has a very good derivation of the Green functions.